# Top tabs showing, although users do not have access to them

Tags: wss-3.0, navigation, security-trimming

We have a wss3.0 site with forms-based authentication.

We have a lot of sites. The Top tabs are showing, although users do not have access to them. When they select them they are prompted for a login, so that works fine, but I only want to display the ones they have access to.

Thanks
Jacobus

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to handle navigation links; linked objects and manually defined links.

With Linked Objects the security trimming is in place.  This could be a link to a site, list, or page if you are using server w/ publishing.  You can configure the navigation to show all sites.

In some cases though where there are a LOT of sites, users decide to only show specific links and they will manually define the links.  In this case SharePoint doesn't know the difference between a site on your server and something like microsoft.com so there is no security trimming.  All users will be shown the links, and if they click on a tab that they do not have access, they will be shown the access denied screen.

It sounds like you need to step back and provide better planning for the navigation, and perhaps the overall site topology.  It isn't a great idea in most cases to have a ton of sub-sites within a single site collection.

Answer (score 0):

If these are links that you manually added to the global navigation you can set the audience for each of them to only show the the links to the people you want to see them.  With manually created links/headers SharePoint doesn't have a way to automatiicaly security trim them.

If these are links that SharePoint added automatically (you selected to show pages/subsites in the global navigation) they should be security trimmed automatically.

Comment: with WSS, there is no audiences feature.